# Find function and regex in lua

Tags: lua

```
 local ct = s:find('[ \t]', 80)
```

find function in Lua is generally used to find a particular pattern in a given string.  In above line of code, we are passing '[ \t]' as the pattern to find along with 80.

What does it mean to pass [ \t] as the pattern to find and where is this 80 coming from? 
As far as I know, find function takes only two parameters i.e the string and the pattern to find.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `[ \t]` matches one space or one tab.

The match is attempted starting at position 80 in the given string.

[`string.find`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.find) accepts two optional arguments besides the string and the pattern.